# remove user.config during uninstall in a MSI admin install/uninstall using Group Policy object (GPO)

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation, user.config

We have a user.config file that is created in C:\Users\ [User] \AppData\Local[Company][Project Name].vshos_Url_zw3i045fzlcuakzzn3dtaw3fqgh03sub\1.0.0.0\ directory and would like to remove the user.config file so that we can leave the clients computer in Clean state on Uninstall.

Now some of our clients are big corporations that perform the deployment using GPO to 100's of computers and the way in which GPO does the install is it installs when the computer is rebooted and before the user logs in, in case of "assigned application -> Computer configuration"

The issue is since the MSI install/uninstall process takes place before the user logs in, it makes it impossible to create a custom action that will accept a path which can resolve to users profile folder that  holds the user.config file. Can someone please help me with this issue.

I had success achieving this using Custom Actions in environments where user installs the product after he/she is logged in but not in a corporate environment using GPO.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Windows Installer support for removing files
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371201(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT: I seems that this is not possible event with WI support.

Comment: Hi Ciprian, Thanks a lot for your response. I have already used Remove files table to implement that in environment where user intalls the product as opposed to corporate environment where GPO's are used and installation takes place pre user login.